# is this a correct ottoman map in year 1803m

Tags: ancient-history

I found this map on the internet .. in the comments many people said it might be wrong.

> 1-The name of the countries are wrong  with wrong border.
>
> 2-Its too accurate.
>
> 3-Its not arabic language either its not ottoman.

This is the most critics about the map.

So is this map correct ?

I think its not because the name of the countries. But what about the accuracy and its langauge

[image]

Comment: Map is not uploaded 5 minutes after original post (rather than 1 min promised). Has there been an error?

Comment: @StuartAllan ok done

Comment: The full map of the world appears here: https://c2.staticflickr.com/2/1556/23923335665_6d6c9612cf_o.png   Note that Tasmania is shown as a peninsula, even though it had been proven to be an island in 1798.  Michigan and the Great Lakes are very distorted, as is common on early maps.

Comment: Here is the official map of the US, published by the Ottomans in 1803, with an article discussing it.  This article describes the writing as "slightly modified Arabic script.": http://www.slate.com/blogs/the_vault/2014/10/16/history_of_the_ottoman_empire_ottoman_map_of_the_united_states_in_1803.html   The American coast line varies between the two maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Cedid Atlas. See link below.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cedid_Atlas